# Capturing whole ToolStripMenu tree with ToString

Tags: c#, toolstripmenu

If I run the code in varying areas of my menu tree, I only get the one element, how would you firstly apply this logic to all sub components of this menu tree and secondly, illustrate the whole tree.

The code I have only shows 1 stage of each area applied

```
  MessageBox.Show((ToolStripMenuItem).ToString());
```

So the above would only show File or Save or Open, rather than File Open or File Save.

Should I be using a foreach with my toolstripmenuitems?

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: yeah mate, cut straight from the compiler. I've simply used the messagebox.show for a quick view of the tostring conversion

Comment: What type is `MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem`?

Comment: apologies, meant to cut out my renamed version, this is simply a toolStripMenuItem

Comment: do you want to search through one top-level menu item (such as File) or through all the top-level menu items (get all children of File, Edit, View etc)?

Comment: The latter, I'm hoping to have the start of the root through each child item to illustrate your whole tree selection

Comment: oops, now i saw your comment. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a logic around the following syntax, then building up the string at the end

```
ToolStripMenuItem ThisMenuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
string WhatClicked = ThisMenuItem.ToString();
ToolStripMenuItem ThisMenuItemOwnerItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)(ThisMenuItem.GetCurrentParent() as ToolStripDropDown).OwnerItem;
```

Then you can obviously get deeper with

```
ToolStripMenuItem ThisOwnersOwnerItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)(ThisMenuItemOwnerItem.GetCurrentParent() as ToolStripDropDown).OwnerItem;
```

and so forth adding checks to avoid null exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have `MenuStrip` with `ToolStripMenuItem` named `fileToolStripMenuItem` (with text `File`) which have subitems `New` and `Open`. Furthermore, `Open` has `From file` and `Recent`. To access all `File`'s `ToolStripMenuItems` (it's children), you need recursive method, which goes through all levels (to access children, grandchildren...)

```
private IEnumerable<ToolStripMenuItem> GetChildToolStripItems(ToolStripMenuItem parent)
{
    if (parent.HasDropDownItems)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem child in parent.DropDownItems)
        {
            
            yield return child;

            foreach (var nextLevel in GetChildToolStripItems(child))
            {
                yield return nextLevel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method takes first level menu item and returns `IEnumerable<ToolStripMenuItem>` sou you can then iterate through it (to get name, change some property etc).

Use it like this:

```
var list = GetChildToolStripItems(fileToolStripMenuItem);
```

In my example, that will return you the collection of subitems, like this: `New, Open, From File, Recent`.

You can easily go through collection and get item's text (to display in `MessageBox`, like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", list.Select(x=>x.Text).ToArray()))
```

or, if you prefer, like this:

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in list)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("item named: {0}, with text: {1}", menuItem.Name, menuItem.Text));
}
```

**EDIT**: after I saw comment that OP's idea is to get all items from `MenuStrip`, here's an example for that.

I wrote additional method that takes `MenuStrip` as parameter, iterates throught all `ToolStripMenuItems` and for each item calls `GetChildToolStripItems` method. Returns list of all top level items and all children and grand children...

```
private List<ToolStripMenuItem> GetAllMenuStripItems(MenuStrip menu)
{
    List<ToolStripMenuItem> collection = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menu.Items)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
        collection.AddRange(GetChildToolStripItems(item));
    }
    return collection;
}
```

usage:

```
 var allItems = GetAllMenuStripItems(menuStrip1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The box explicitly says do not use for thanks, but I appreciate the effort you've gone to, just taking time digesting it, but already upmarked. Appreciated